# How to Generate Multiple Predictions Output with KNN Model?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, knn

I am using `predict()` function to generate prediction from KNN model and instead of having one prediction, which is [10] in this case, I want to have the most likely classes.

Is it Possible ?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


df = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx")
X = df.iloc[:,:4]
y = np.array(df['Target']) 

# split into train and test
X_train, 
X_test, 
y_train, 
y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# instantiate learning model (k = 7)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7)

# fitting the model
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict the response
pred = knn.predict(X_test)

#Predict Output
pred= knn.predict([[2,3,90,600]]) 


**Output:**
**[10]**
```

Comment: I'm confused by "multiple predictions that can be provided by the model". What do you mean? Given the input data, a classifier should only predict the most likely class given the training data. You can use `predict_proba` to get the probabilities for the positive and negative class, or for each class in a multilabel classification problem. What, in your mind, should "multiple predictions" look like for the same model and input data?

Comment: Hi @G. Anderson, Sorry for making my Question so confusing, Yes I would like to have the most likely classes,I think 'predict_proba'  works

Comment: So you want to see the confidence of the prediction for each class?

Comment: @Jerry M. Yes Probability or Confidence

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if that works for you. It prints the predictions for each class, for each sample @ShahineGreene

Comment: I wanted to have as output : predictions with highest probability, in descendant order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add something like this:

`print(knn.predict_proba(X_test)`

This will print out something that may look like:
`[x1. x2. x3. x4.]`, showing the probabilities or the confidence for each class. This method will print out that format for each item in the testing set.

Comment: Here what the output look like please note that there are 9 classes in the dataset [[0.14285714 0.14285714 0.         0.28571429 0.         0.28571429
  0.         0.14285714]
 [0.         0.         0.14285714 0.57142857 0.14285714 0.14285714
  0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.14285714 0.57142857 0.14285714 0.14285714
  0.         0.        ]

Comment: That is a correct output. For the single sample in your test data, the KNN model is printing out its confidence levels that the sample belongs to the specified classes. So it accomplishes what you requested :)

Comment: No problem! @ShahineGreene

Comment: Actually I wanted to have as output : predictions with highest probability in order

Comment: `mylist = knn.predict_proba(X_test)` and then `mylist.sort()`